# SQL: Combine Duplicate Rows And Case Statement Values in Final Data Output

Tags: sql, duplicates, subquery, case, distinct

I'm working on a SQL query that counts duplicate records that are based on a text field I am working with: where datasource = 'Web' or 'Internal'.  I am currently using a case statement to count the number of times a record shows that value.  My question is how do I combine the two results into one record that shows a count of both.

I'm attaching a query of what I currently have working, what my output is and what I would like the end result to look like.

```
SELECT id
,lastname
,firstname
,datasource
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Web')
    )THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END WebData
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Internal')
    ) THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END InternalData
,count(id) as countid

FROM Table


GROUP BY
id
,lastname
,firstname
,datasource
```

This currently returns:

```
12345   Jack    Boss    Internal    0   1   1
12241   Eric    Graves  Internal    0   1   1
13300   Su      Lynn    Web         1   0   1
13300   Su      Lynn    Internal    0   1   1
13914   Mark    Ross    Internal    0   2   2
14008   Mitch   Smith   Internal    0   1   1
```

I would like it to return:

```
12345   Jack    Boss    0   1   1
12241   Eric    Graves  0   1   1
13300   Su      Lynn    1   1   2
13914   Mark    Ross    0   2   2
14008   Mitch   Smith   0   1   1
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle? ("*SQL*" is *not* a DBMS product, it's query language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to add the `outer` select for current query with the `Group` on the the columsn you want to do the aggrigate.Just add the `Outer select` to your query,

```
SELECT 
    data.id,
    data.lastname,
    data.firstname,
    SUM(data.WebData) AS WebData,
    SUM(data.InternalData) AS InternalData,
    SUM(data.countid) AS Countid
FROM
    (
       SELECT id,lastname,
              firstname,datasource,
              CASE WHEN Datasource = 'Web' THEN Count(Datasource) ELSE 0 END WebData,
              CASE WHEN Datasource = 'Internal' THEN Count(Datasource)ELSE 0 END InternalData,
             count(id) AS Countid

        FROM Table
        GROUP BY
                 id,lastname,firstname,datasource
     ) AS data
GROUP BY 
    data.id,data.firstname,data.lastname
```

Comment: Thanks, that absolutely did exactly what I needed it to, and now gives me exactly what I need.